# Windows Store App Permission dialog

Tags: windows-8, permissions, dialog, windows-store-apps

I want to use the permission dialog one like OS uses to show the permission while app accessing devices or sensors.

For example if our application is going to use location sensor then the OS will ask the user for permission to allow the app to use the location data.

Windows 8 is showing a very good dialog for the permissions like this, so is there any class/control which let me show the same dialog with my custom data?

Thanks.

Comment: For the metro application, I found the MessageDialog will solve the purpose.

But is there any similar control presents for Desktop app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For desktop apps, you can use the Task Dialog - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756938.aspx